# .NET Service System.IOException "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

In this code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var wa = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    Console.WriteLine("Type: " + wa.AuthenticationType + Environment.NewLine +
                    "ImpersonationLevel: " + wa.ImpersonationLevel + Environment.NewLine +
                    "IsAnonymous: " + wa.IsAnonymous + Environment.NewLine +
                    "IsAuthenticated: " + wa.IsAuthenticated + Environment.NewLine +
                    "IsGuest: " + wa.IsGuest + Environment.NewLine +
                    "IsSystem: " + wa.IsSystem + Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine("Windows Account: " + wa.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + Environment.UserDomainName);
    Console.WriteLine("UserName: " + Environment.UserName);
    Console.WriteLine("Interactive: " + Environment.UserInteractive);
    try
    {
        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"NETWORK SHARED DIRECTORY PATH");
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fail: " + ex.ToString());
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

I try get the files in a shared repository in a server. If excute the program, it work. But if I use RunAs, It throw the exeption :

> System.IOException "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

Except the WriLines in TryCath, the output is the same. The crendential is identical.

Can you help me to resolve this problem?
Maybe I need display other informations?

Thank.

Comment: You sure the user is the exact same? Maybe a local one and a domain one? Displaying the Console output for both scenarios would definitely help.